# How can I have apache load and display folders stored in a shared folder on another machine?

Tags: html, apache, samba

I am running an apache server on computer A. I use computer B with ubuntu desktop and A lamp server to develop code because it's more portable. I use ftp to put html files on computer A and they can be opened by connecting to computer A's ip via the browser, all simple enough. Now I would like via a link on my default page `index.html` to be redirected to an html file stored in a shared folder on computer B. Is such a thing possible and if so how can I make apache render the html page at such a location as `smb://<network location>/var/www`?

Comment: Mount the remote folder, and set the mount point as the DocumentRoot?

Comment: I want to keep the document root so that the server is still functional when my laptop (computer b) is not connected to the network. In other words, leave it where it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. mkdir /var/www/remote # assuming your current document root is /var/www/
2. mount smb://network.host/var/www /var/www/remote/

Once you have it working you can edit `/etc/fstab` to make it permanent, or script **step 2**.
This will keep your current local server working, and allow you to access the remote path at `http://127.0.0.1/remote/`

Comment: To clarify, var/www is on computer b.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. I'm getting errors, is `network.host` literal or do I use the host computer name? I'm a complete noob when it comes to home networks and network addressing in linux.

Comment: It is not literal. Replace it with the remote computer name.

Comment: I tried that and get the following errors: "wrong fs type" "bad option" "bad superblock".

Comment: @CraigPatrickLafferty Is the remote host on windows? And are you sure you've shared "/var/www"?

Comment: You could also use a reverse http proxy for some path.

Comment: The remote host is linux and I'm positive.